# python - Opening another tkinter window with opencv camera don't show live feed

Tags: python, tkinter, camera, window

I have 2 windows, first is the main window (window1) and another window with opencv (window2). I have a button on window1 that opens window2. Whenever I open window2 on window1 the camera won't show on the GUI. But if I open window2 individually which is on a different file, the camera is showing.

I tried to put it on a single python file, and it still doesn't work, the camera is still not showing.

Comment: Are the two windows instances of `Tk()`?

Comment: Would you provide minimum reproducible code? Then we can see what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: you can't mix different types of GUI (OpenCV, tkinter). if you have a tkinter gui already, show your images in tkinter. do not use `imshow`.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I fixed it by removing the main loop on window2 since camera window2 also runs in tkinter.